# How to simultaneously access two arrays indexes for a curl request in Bash for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

In Bash i am trying to query country currencies 
 from http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_GBP and update my OpenEdge API automatically without Hard coding the symbols. meaning I have to curl and save currency symbols from my API in an array and curl and save the values from the currency converter API. after that i want to run two for loops simultaneously or access the indexes of two arrays at the same time in order to run the API call that requires the

```
url/rest/USD/12
```

kind of input.

In bash I am calling a curl that returns

```
ZAR USD EUR BWP CHF GBP
```

from my API in one line. Then i save that result in a variable called currency

```
jsonEnd="_ZAR.val"
symbolEnd="_ZAR"
```

I then run

```
values=()
for j in ${currency[*]};
do
        ${values[j]}=$(curl -X GET -H "Content-type: application/json" http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=${currency[j]}$symbolEnd&compact=y | jq '.${currency[j]}$jsonEnd')         
done
```

To get the currency values into an array where '_ZAR.val' is a from a json result, tried to point at "val" with jq

```
{
"USD_ZAR": {
    "val": 14.23065
} }
```

at last i am trying to run a POST Curl which needs the relative currency symbol found above like USD with a value to update.
in this form

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: $context" http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/rest/exchangerates/USD/12
```

i tried this

```
for i in ${values[@]}
do    
      curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: $context" http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/rest/exchangerates/${currency[i]}/${values[i]}
done
```

i can't get it right, the errors include

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: USD_ZAR
```

etc 
I am new to bash

Comment: can you include full code as well?

Comment: I don't get where OpenEdge comes into play here. (Mentioned in the text and in the tag.)

Comment: i'm sorry, i'll remove it, it's coming from fact that the API it's calling is made in OpenEdge REST lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `${currency[*]}` and `${currency[*]}` will expand to the *values* inside the array. So when you write ...

```
for j in "${currency[@]}"; do
    echo "${currency[j]}"         
done
```

... you do not access something like `${currency[0]}` but `${currency[USD]}` which does not exist.

Also, to assign variables you cannot write `${array[i]}=value` but have to use `array[$i]=value`.

You may also want to switch to an associative array (also known as *dictionary* or *map*) where you can use strings as indices. Here is a rough skeleton:

```
currencies=(ZAR USD EUR BWP CHF GBP)
declare -A values
for c in "${currencies[@]}"; do
    values["$c"]="$(curl ..."$c"... | jq ..."$c"... )"
done

c=EUR
echo "The value of $c is ${values[$c]}"
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me. my main problem was the string of currency symbols, it was not coming in as an array, it was a flat string, has to convert it to an array and the above solution made the syntax errors to go away, and the script to Run! lol thank you